# Form Fill Paste then Tab Repeat

Tags: forms, tabs, applescript, copy-paste

I am trying to script some data entry using a applescript.

I need it to paste and then tab seven times and then paste again..... 2700 times.

While I am very new to programming, I was at least able to get something working.

What I have so far:

```
set the clipboard to "blah"
tell application "blah"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat 4 times
            keystroke "v" using {command down}
            keystroke "                         "
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Now this will paste into the first form and then skip one and paste into the next one. I dont know why. So this just pastes into every other form.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
set the clipboard to "blah"
tell application "blah"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat 4 times
            keystroke "v" using {command down}
            delay 1
            repeat 7 times
                keystroke tab
                delay 1
            end repeat
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.
That enters blah into the first form, jumps 4 lines, and then pastes 7 blahs.

Comment: The paste command is only being sent 4 times. I don't see how it would paste 7 times.

Comment: I hear ya, its like it gets stuck after the it tabs. Looking into a few things.

Comment: I edited the answer to include delays. Also, if you give more background about the application you are targeting, users may be able to provide a better solution.

Comment: hehe yep that is what i just did as well.

Comment: Ya it was the delay.

I switched `keystroke tab` to `keystroke (ASCII character 9) --keystroke tab`

and entered in a delay of 0.2